# In Drupal 7 views how to give external link (another website) to a title?

Tags: drupal-7, view, drupal-views, content-type

Iam new to drupal 7 views.
I have a content type contains title, description fields. I want the content title's to scroll at the top of the page, so that i created a view and it works fine.What is my question is, i want to link a content (eg: 1st content (title) in a scroll) to another website instead of content page, the remaining contents linked to the content page. Is it possible?.If it is possible how it can be done?..

Thanks in advance,
A.John Melchior.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.
One way to do it, would be to use the [Link](http://drupal.org/project/link) module to create a link field in your node. 
Use the link field to input the external link value.
In views add the link field, before the title ( order is important ) and exclude it from display
Add the node title field in the views and in the rewrite field output option, use one the link field token as your path.
I'm not looking at the Views UI right now , but you should find at least a couple of ways to redirect content when the node title is clicked. You should have the Rewrite field output and the Output this field as a link.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of Display Suite coupled with the description above.

Create a link field for your nodes.

Create 2 view modes for your content type via Display Suite. View Mode 1 will show the link field as the first data element, View Mode 2 will show the title as the first element.

Configure your view to show output using Display Suite, configured to show the first record using View Mode 1, all others using View Mode 2.